# Retrieve data from elasticsearch results

Tags: c#, .net, elasticsearch, nest

I'm writing a method that will search on elastic search for a determined query string, I get the results with several data such as Highlights, Hits, score; But I want only to get and access the data that is within the Documents, how can I achieve that in C#?

This is my code so far:

```
public string GetByOpinionDocumentTextElastic(string queryString)
    {
        var settings = new ConnectionSettings(new Uri(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ElasticSearchAddress"])).SetDefaultIndex("caselaw");
        var client = new ElasticClient(settings);

        var result = client.Search<OpinionDocumentIndexRecord>(body => body.Query(query => query.QueryString(qs => qs.Query(queryString))));


    }
```

What should my method return? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Where you get your documents from can depend based on the version of Nest you are using. From the [Nest 1.0 Breaking Changes page](http://nest.azurewebsites.net/breaking-changes.html):

> **DocumentsWithMetaData**
>
> When you do a search with NEST 0.12 you'd get back a `QueryResponse<T>` with two ways to loop over your results. `.Documents` is an `IEnumerable<T>` and `.DocumentsWithMetaData` is and `IEnumerable<IHit<T>>` depending on your needs one of them might be easier to use.
>
> Starting from NEST 1.0 `.DocumentsWithMetaData` is now called simply `.Hits`.

So given your code example:

NEST 0.12

```
 result.Documents

 result.DocumentsWithMetaData
```

NEST 1.0

```
  result.Hits
```

The biggest difference with the 0.12 properties is that `.Documents` are just a collection of the results from the search, mapped directly to your type `OpinionDocumentIndexRecord`. While `.DocumentsWithMetaData` have additional Elasticsearch properties like Highlights, Fields, Explanation, Type, available along with the Source property being your `OpinionDocumentIndexRecord`. Which you need or want will most likely depend upon your specific application/business needs.

So if you are using Nest 0.12.0 and want a solution that will easily port to Nest 1.0.0, I would recommend using `.DocumentsWithMetaData` and then you can just change to `.Hits` when you upgrade the Nest Client.

If you truly only care about the `OpinionDocumentIndexRecord` regardless of what property you access off of the results, then you can use one of the folllowing:

```
 var myData = new List<OpinionDocumentIndexRecord>();
 foreach (var hit in results.DocumentsWithMetaData)
 //foreach (var hit in results.Hits) //for Nest 1.0
 {
       myData.Add(hit.Source);
 }

 return myData;
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: What happens when you  select a limited amount of fields?  source is null in that case?

Comment: Aaron- The answer you're looking for may be here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28306464/261405