# Convert NEST (Elasticsearch) Search Results to DataSet - C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, elasticsearch, dataset, nest

I am using NEST to search my Elasticsearch index:

```
        var result = client.Search<MyObject>(s => s
            .From(0)
            .Size(10)
            // Query here
);
```

This works and returns a Nest.SearchResponse object. The format returned by `result.Hits.ToList()` is `List<Nest.IHit<MyObject>>()`.

How can I convert the results returned to a DataSet (or DataTable)?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Does this Hits.ToList() functionality still exist? I'm trying to use it but it won't work for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to loop over your results

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("Field1", typeof(string));
dt.Columns.Add("Field2", typeof(string));
...
foreach (IHit<JObject> x in result.Hits)
{
   dt.Rows.Add(
       x.Fields.FieldValuesDictionary["Prop1"] as JArray,
       x.Fields.FieldValuesDictionary["Prop2"] as JArray
       ...
   );
}
```

Read

- [Retrieve data from elasticsearch results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23394270/retrieve-data-from-elasticsearch-results)
- [How do you get search results returned in nest 1.x mapped to an object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25416216/how-do-you-get-search-results-returned-in-nest-1-x-mapped-to-an-object)

as well as

> DocumentsWithMetaData
>
> When you do a search with NEST 0.12, you'd get back a QueryResponse
>   with two ways to loop over your results. .Documents is an
>   IEnumerable and .DocumentsWithMetaData is and IEnumerable>
>   depending on your needs one of them might be easier to use.
>
> Starting from NEST 1.0 .DocumentsWithMetaData is now called simply
>   .Hits.

http://nest.azurewebsites.net/breaking-changes.html

Comment: Thanks for the great answer and resources.

Answer (score 1):

As proposed in this [article](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/784090/Conversion-Between-DataTable-and-List-in-Csharp), you can use an extension method to convert an `IEnumerable<T>` to a `DataTable`:

```
public static class IEnumerableExtensions
{
    /*Converts IEnumerable To DataTable*/
    public static DataTable ToDataTable<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> data)
    {
        DataTable dataTable = new DataTable(typeof(TSource).Name);
        PropertyInfo[] props = typeof(TSource).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
        foreach (PropertyInfo prop in props)
        {
            dataTable.Columns.Add(prop.Name, Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(prop.PropertyType) ??
                prop.PropertyType);
        }

        foreach (TSource item in data)
        {
            var values = new object[props.Length];
            for (int i = 0; i < props.Length; i++)
            {
                values[i] = props[i].GetValue(item, null);
            }
            dataTable.Rows.Add(values);
        }
        return dataTable;
    }  
}
```

Then, after the search you could do something like this:

```
var dataTable = result.Documents.ToDataTable();
```

Where `Documents` is an `IEnumerable<MyObject>` that are the documents inside the hits that are returned. Another way to obtain those documents is:

```
var documents=result.Hits.Select(h => h.Source);
```